# Send/Receive Files PHP Script

Tags: php

I need to create a script to read files and post the data so it can be received on another machine.

Does anyone have any ideas on where I could begin with this? The only thing on PHP.Net that looks like something similar is using `dir("/etc/php5`

Answer (score 1):

With PHP you can use `libcurl` to upload the file to a remote server. You don't need to do anything special to read the file, just give the path to curl. Here is an example for sending the file:

```
$target_url = 'http://127.0.0.1/accept.php';
//This needs to be the full path to the file you want to send.
$file_name_with_full_path = realpath('./sample.jpeg');
/* curl will accept an array here too.
 * Many examples I found showed a url-encoded string instead.
 * Take note that the 'key' in the array will be the key that shows up in the
 * $_FILES array of the accept script. and the at sign '@' is required before the
 * file name.
 */
$post = array('extra_info' => '123456','file_contents'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

This code is from Derak, see http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/ for all the details.

Note that you don't really need PHP for this at all, [you can simply use `curl` from the command line](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) or with a shell script.

Comment: Your link doesn't work. Gateway error. Can you post the details in your answer?

Comment: Link is fine for me, but I updated the answer with more details.

Comment: Link now working for me also, but thank you for posting code. Best for future readers should that site have problems again.

Answer (score 0):

Use  XML PHP function to parse the data to a dump file then read it with a different function on the other machine.